# How can i get UDID from http request sent form an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, http, http-headers

I need to track requests for each mobile device, and for that to happen I need the unique identifier.

Does the iPhone send UDID in each HTTP request header? If yes how could I read it? What is the name of the header?

Comment: why the down vote? please elaborate ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not, but you could add it to the HTTP GET/POST request.

Either way I would recommend against as you should generate your own.

Answer (score 1):

No, the iPhone does not send the UDID or any other unique identifier.